# Loop over name list in a ShinyApps server.R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, shiny, infobox

While trying to create a series of InfoBoxes for a Shiny project, I've come across a loop that even though I've endlessly tried to solve, ends up in me pasting the code as many times as InfoBoxes I need, which is incredibly.
My original chunk of code is something like this

```
output$**name** <- renderValueBox({
  InformacionIE2 <- InformacionIE2.df[ which(InformacionIE2.df$INSTITUCIONEDUCATIVA==input$input_typen),]
  if (InformacionIE2$**name** =="Si") {
    infoBox("Planos Electricos",
            color = "green",
            icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
            print (InformacionIE2$**name**)
    )
  } else {
    infoBox("**name** ",
            color = "red",
            icon = icon("thumbs-down", lib = "glyphicon"),
            print (InformacionIE2$**name**)
    )          
  }
})
```

What I need is to find a way for name1, name2, name3, ..., nameN to iterate in place of **name** in that exact same chunk of code without having to copy paste as namy times as names there are. 
I tried to do this with a simple loop over a list, but get back an error telling me there is a syntax error near unexpected token.

How could this be solved?

Comment: access outout via $ string will not work. Try output[["name"]] instead, same for InformacionIE2. If that does not help, a reproducible app would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lapply` instead of a for loop and it should work. No clue why:

```
lapply(**names**, function(name) {
output[[name]] <- <- renderValueBox({
  InformacionIE2 <- InformacionIE2.df[ which(InformacionIE2.df$INSTITUCIONEDUCATIVA==input$input_typen),]
  if (InformacionIE2[[name]] =="Si") {
    infoBox("Planos Electricos",
            color = "green",
            icon = icon("thumbs-up", lib = "glyphicon"),
            print (InformacionIE2[[name]])
    )
  } else {
    infoBox(name,
            color = "red",
            icon = icon("thumbs-down", lib = "glyphicon"),
            print (InformacionIE2[[name]])
    )          
  }
})
})
```